# Symfony 3 Deploying to Azure - Route Problems

Tags: php, git, azure, symfony

I created an project and now i`m trying to deploy to Azure.

Started with lots of problems... I cant deploy using bitbucket... Azure just return an error every time saying there is an error with a file in Cache directory... I cleared the directory and shows same error.

I uploaded using FTP.

Now, i got this problem:

here is my url:

```
http://attrative.azurewebsites.net/
```

Nothing happens... I need use the complete path:

```
http://attrative.azurewebsites.net/web/app.php
```

Ok, ok, worked... but when logged in, i used the route name="plataforma" and when login, Symfony redirects to this path:

```
http://attrative.azurewebsites.net/plataforma
```

On localhost, it works perfectly... But on azure, it just works if i mannualy change the url to:

```
http://attrative.azurewebsites.net/web/app.php/plataforma
```

How can i fix this problem?
And there is a way to deploy using git? I followed the tutorial at this link with no success:

[Symfony Cookbook - Deploying to Microsoft Azure Website Cloud](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/deployment/azure-website.html)

Thanks for the tips...

Comment: Have you configured URL rewrite mod in the `web.config` as shown at http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/deployment/azure-website.html#configure-the-web-server ?

Comment: @GaryLiu-MSFT I love you! the answer in link, do not help so much, but in a link inside the link you give, helped a lot... 18h trying this and finnaly!!! thanks... "may the force be with you!"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Gary Liu - MSFT.

He gives an link to documentation where i found this link:

[Git - symfony-azure-edition](https://github.com/beberlei/symfony-azure-edition/blob/master/web.config)

And at this link, i got this `web.config` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <defaultDocument enabled="true">
            <files>
                <clear />
                <add value="app.php" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <clear />
                <rule name="blockAccessToPublic" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="*" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                        <add input="{URL}" pattern="/web/*" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="403" statusReason="Forbidden: Access is denied." statusDescription="You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied." />
                </rule>
                <rule name="RewriteAssetsToPublic" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)(\.css|\.js|\.jpg|\.png|\.gif)$" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="web/{R:0}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="RewriteRequestsToPublic" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)$" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="web/app.php/{R:0}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Just put in root folder and ta-da!!!!

Problem solved!!!